# grunt get all content to a new file

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, mean-stack

I do have the following source-view

[image]

Is it possible, with grunt, to take all those files into for example a file called `content.js` and load that instead? so `content.js` will contain all the code, when the requests to the server is made?

Im asking for a way to do this automatically.

**EDIT**

tried out https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat
but with these details:

```
  dist: {
        src: ['modules/*/client/*/*.js'],
        dest: 'public/js/built.js',
      },
```

dont seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's possible. Use [`grunt-contrib-concat`](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat):

```
// minimum example:
grunt.initConfig({
  concat: {
    options: {
      separator: ';',
    },
    dist: {
      src: ['src/path/to/your/scripts/**/*.js'], // if you need some specific order
                                                 // list files or directories individually
                                                 // and read below's recommendation                            
      dest: 'dist/built.js',
    },
  },
});
```

However, considering the fact that your project looks somewhat extensive, I would rather recommend making the larger step to some more "intelligent" dependency management, such as [Browserify](http://browserify.org) or [Webpack](http://webpack.github.io).

Comment: i cant see that the destination file is created?

Comment: Then something is not configured correctly :) Please provide more details.

Comment: can we take a chat? @qqilihq

Comment: Not now, I'm already halfway on my way home. Feel free to edit your original question. Either someone else will answer, or I can have a look tomorrow.

Comment: @maria (a) Have you verified, that the `concat` task is executed? Is it shown when running grunt? (b) Is the path correctly specified?